# IN Django IF ELSE Not Working within For Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for product in products:
    for dess in peice:
        for cell in sell:
            try:
                if product == dess:
                    print(123)
                else:
                    if product == sell:
                        print(456)
                    else:
                        print(nothing)
            except:
                pass
```

> I try to run this type of for loop with if else. but if 1st statement
>   run then out from loop and not show any result. can you check what is
>   issue ?

Comment: Your program is ungrammatical. Please check your indents before posting.

Comment: @Amadan don't focus on grammer. logical anwer me. my english is not good.

Comment: There are two collumns here in `if product == sell::`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem update now.

Comment: I don't care about English. Your _Python_ is ungrammatical. Without correct indent. there's no way to know what your original code was supposed to do, or where the error is.

Comment: @gogaz now check but still not working

Comment: What is the value of  `products`, `peice`, `sell` and `nothing`? What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Amadan actually my question is big so i tried to make short. but :/